# How to track down a leak in Go?

Tags: go

My project prints a lot of:

```
transport: http2Client.notifyError got notified that the client transport was broken EOF.
```

The project itself is an HTTP proxy using Go's standard HTTP server and client and calls other services over GRPC. Is there any way I can figure out which piece is leaking?

Comment: Check out this blog post: [The Go Blog: Introducing HTTP Tracing](https://blog.golang.org/http-tracing)

Comment: What makes you think that this is a "leak"? What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Why would it be logging this if it wasn't a leak? For some reason this app is also going out of file handles every once in a while.

Comment: Seeing unexpected EOFs doesn't indicate a leak, but running out of resources like file descriptors does. Do you have timeouts around _everything_? You can't ever count on remote clients and servers responding in a specific timeframe.

Comment: This actually points out to there being stuff being leaked: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/issues/954

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares: that looks suspicious, but that doesn't necessarily look like it would leak connections. A good starting point is to look at the open file descriptors for the process and see what connections are being left open -- should you be looking at GRPC at all, or is this an http server issue?